# multiple checkbox actions

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to make multiple checkboxes and every time I check one of them the value of the first input reduce by a number for example when we select checkbox1 the number in input reduces by 10 and when we select checkbox2 it reduces by 20 and when we select both of them it reduces by 30. 
I have handled the first checkbox though.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" id="input">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="one()" id="checkboxId">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="" id="checkboxId2">
    <p id="par">hello</p>
    <script>
        function one () {
            var check = document.getElementById("checkboxId");
        if (check.checked) {
            let input = document.getElementById("input").value;
            y = input - 10;
            document.getElementById("par").innerHTML = y;
        } else {
             document.getElementById("par").innerHTML=document.getElementById("input").value;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using ***data-**** attribute. Also, you can get the value only from the checked check boxes, sum them and deduct that from the input value.

Try the following way:

```js
function one () {
  var total = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(':checked'))
              .map(el => el.getAttribute('data-value'))
              .reduce((a,c) => a+ Number(c), 0);
   document.getElementById("par").textContent = Number(document.getElementById("input").value) - total;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="one()" data-value="10" id="checkboxId">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="one()" data-value="20" id="checkboxId2">
<p id="par">hello</p>
```